# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null laravel crud?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

The name of controller is "BadgeController". This is my store function in BadgeController where is this error happening.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('images');
    $new_name = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
    $form_data = array(
        'image' => $new_name,
    );

    Badge::create($form_data);

    return redirect('badges.index')->with('success', 'Data Added successfully.');
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the native file `store` method that returns the path with a unique image name? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: Did your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error, it means your validation is successfully passed, so I guess the input's name is `image` not `images`.

```
$image = $request->file('image');
```